# Powerapps: Form Column changes depending on Choice Value in preceding Column

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a Sharepoint List like so, with each column being a Choice column with the options Complete, On Track, At Risk, Overdue:

```
 Id    Stage 1   Stage 2   Stage 3   Stage 4

 1    Complete  On Track  On Track  On Track
```

This appears as a Form in my Powerapp. When I change Stage 2 to 'At Risk' or 'Overdue', I need Stage 3 and Stage 4 to automatically change to 'At Risk' also.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, here are two examples. The first one is done in your PowerApp:

**OnSelect Event of your submit:**

```
If(
    DropDownStage2.Selected.Value = 'At Risk' ||
    DropDownStage2.Selected.Value = 'Overdue',
        Patch(ThisItem, 
            {
                Stage2: DropDownStage2.Selected.Value,
                Stage3: 'At Risk',
                Stage4: 'At Risk'
            }
        ),
    Patch(ThisItem,
        {
            Stage2: DropDownStage2.Selected.Value
        }
    )
)
```

The second option is using a power automate.

Choose the trigger of type when a sharepoint item is created or modified and select your list. When a record is created with stage 2 your criteria, update stage 3 and 4.

G'luck